# how to write sqlite query using coredata

Tags: iphone

Please help me,

I want to write query(mentioned below) using coredata.

```
select primKey, ( primKey - 5 ) as **d** from TABLE Order by **d** limit 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot - CoreData is not an ORM or a Database and doesn't claim to be. it MAY be backed by SQL lite (or it might not) but that is an implementation detail.

[see some of the other times this has come up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959402/which-are-the-most-noteable-things-which-make-working-with-core-data-different-th/2959580#2959580) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800835/core-data-3-table-join)

You will need to use an NSPredicate for your fetch